# Moving Socket connection between processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, multiprocessing

I want to create a [socket server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) running on Node.js that listens to *N* ports, for each of these ports a different client would connect to it. When they are all connected, I would like to create *N/2* [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (workers) and "delegate" two of these socket connections to each. When the work is done it should return the socket connection to the main process. I'm not sure if this is possible.

My solution right now is to redirect the socket messages using `child_process.send(data)`. I am concerned this adds another layer of communication and consequently more overhead and I would like to avoid that and just pass the socket session to the child processes. I can't tell the clients to reconnect or disconnect them at any moment for that purpose.

I looked over [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) but it seems it only shares connections between the child processes but not with the master as well. Unless I make the "real master" just a dummy for starting all the processes and make the "smart master" as a sibling of the others.

Is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: File handles are not something you can exchange between processes without forking, something that the Node.js core doesn't support for portability reasons. Is proxying an option here? There's also an option on an OS like Linux to have several processes listening to the same port and sharing incoming connections, the OS can do load-balancing for you. As always, you can use a dedicated load balancer like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

Comment: Actually I'm forking (child processes), so that's not the issue. Also they are net.Socket, not file handlers, are they related?

Comment: Every socket at the low level is a file handle, that's how the OS works. Also the fork in Node.js isn't the same as a POSIX `fork`.

Comment: @tadman is 100% correct. I'd add that proxying the connections through 127.0.0.1 is quite an efficient thing to do on any remotely modern OS. It doesn't actually hit the network adapter and so won't 'steal' traffic from your server. It does have a small hit on CPU, but you're not going to notice it.